# Question about interrole conflict

Tags: social-psychology, stress, workload, conflict

Katz & Kahn defined the interrole conflict as a conflict between two roles that are incompatibles, or when more than one person has the same role.

I had a question today in an exam about role conflicts induced stress in the workplace and wondered if someone could shed some light about this.

Its a true/false question that goes like this:

```
A policeman is in a situation where he must rescue someone while risking his own security.
This is an interrole conflict. (T/F)
```

I wrote false, because the question does not imply the policeman necessarily has other roles in conflict with this one. For example what if he doesn't have any family, any friends, etc.? But I ain't sure! Is simply being alive an implicit role? Is being healthy and in a state of security a role?

Isn't it more an intra role conflict then? In the sense his job probably doesn't ask for him having to put his own security at risk? I found this one quite difficult to answer.

I would like some opinions on this! I want to understand this correctly.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Just a thought here, if the police officer risks his own security, is he not putting others at risk of having to help him?

Comment: What is Katz & Kahn referring to?

Comment: @ChrisRogers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role_conflict#Inter-role Interrole is a conflict between two roles that somewhat are not compatible. I'm not sure the question implies the policeman puts others at risk. I have little idea about what is implicit or not. I guess nothing is.